# Best coding Style - Checking if a character is a valid character

Tags: java, checkstyle

I am coding a method that returns whether a given character is valid, which looks like this: -

```
private static boolean isValid(char c) {
    return c == '.' || c == ',' || c == '+' || c == '/' || c == ';' || c == ':';
}
```

Check style flagged this up as the boolean complexity is too great (5 when it should be no more than 3). My development manager has flagged up a few alternative implementations which I will post as answers. Personally, I think my code is readable enough and would prefer to turn off check style for this method.

What do you think?

Comment: This method makes it more of a pain to add characters or remove them compared to others, and harder to see at a glance which characters are valid.

Comment: Make your poll answers c/w or it looks like reputation farming.

Comment: @Tom: Using regular expressions for this would work but be very slow (in comparison) and give no added value at all apart from maybe the satisfaction in showing others that your hammer can be used with any nail.

Comment: Why has this been closed? It is a real question and I made the answers community wiki.

Answer (score 12):

```
private static boolean isValid(char c) {
    String validChars =".,+/;:";
    return (validChars.indexOf(c) > -1);
}
```

Comment: This is an ok solution, but it does not scale well.  For that, you need a lookup table.

Comment: I'd extract what's a valid character into a property file so you don't have to recompile the code to change the list of valid characters.

Answer (score 5):

```
private static boolean isValid(char c) {
    switch (c) {
    case '.' : // FALLTHROUGH
    case ',' : // FALLTHROUGH
    case '+' : // FALLTHROUGH
    case '/' : // FALLTHROUGH
    case ';' : // FALLTHROUGH
    case ':' :
      return true;
    default : return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the case of alternative case statements, I wouldn't bother with the //FALLTHROUGH comments.

Comment: I like this one the best because it's the simplest.  If speed is not an issue I ALWAYS go for readiblity because you never know who is going to have to maintain  your code when you are not around.

Comment: I quite dislike this one because it's bulky and inflexible.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static boolean isValid(char c) {
    /* CHECKSTYLE:OFF */
    return c == '.' || c == ',' || c == '+' || c == '/' || c == ';' || c == ':';
    /* CHECKSTYLE:ON */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a Set. It has the benefit of having a descriptive name, and it scales well.

```
private static Set<Character> validCharacters = new HashSet<Character>();

public static void initValidCharacters() {
    validCharacters.add('.');
    validCharacters.add(',');
    validCharacters.add('+');
    validCharacters.add('/');
    validCharacters.add(';');
    validCharacters.add(':');
}

private static boolean isValid(char c) {
    return validCharacters.contains(c);
}
```

Comment: This would work, the only downside would be the auto-boxing overhead on each check?

Answer (score 1):

```
private static boolean isValid(char c) {
    char[] validChars2 = {'.', ',', '+', '/', ';', ':'};
    for (char d : validChars2) {
      if (c == d) { return true; }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression could work well.  I've hard-coded it into the example below, but you could just as easily pull it out of a config file.

```
    [Test]
    public void AisNotValid ()
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(IsValid('a'));
    }

    [Test]
    public void SemiColonIsValid ()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(IsValid(';'));
    }

    public bool IsValid(Char c)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(Regex.Escape(".,+/;:"), c.ToString());
    }
```

The Regex.Escape() method comes in handy here because it escapes characters that normally have meaning in a Regex. From the docs: "Escapes a minimal set of characters (\, *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #, and white space) by replacing them with their escape codes."

Comment: Nice, down-voted for using a different (but VERY similar) language? Weak.

Comment: I might downvote on the basis of regexp being overkill, but C# is so similar to Java that I didn't even notice.

Answer (score 0):

If readability is not a concern, this can be dealt with a semi binary search, with boolean complexity of 3

As a reference for char values

```
+ 11
, 12
. 14
/ 15
: 26
; 27

private static boolean isValid(char c)
{
    return c > 14 ? c == '/' || c == ';' || c == ':' : c == '.' || c == ',' || c == '+';
}
```

Comment: Binary searches are often faster than linear, but for so few elements, the overhead of the more sophisticated algorithm may well not be worth it.  A simple look-up table would be faster, and would remain fast no matter how many characters were being tested for.